# Why is "hiccup" spelled with two c's?

Tags: etymology, orthography, history, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Is there a historical or grammatical reason for spelling hiccup with two c's?

Comment: Chambers says "*an earlier form was* **hicket**". Perhaps the fact that it's often spelt *hiccough* (same word, pronounced the same) was instrumental in encouraging the adoption/retention of "cc" instead of "ck".

Comment: My husband was just making fun of me the other day for having spelled it hiccough!  Then, now, on a spelling scavenger hunt I have found this nifty little resource.  Thanks for asking the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=hiccup&searchmode=none) gives earlier spellings and foreign spellings:

> **hiccup (n.)**
> 1570s, *hickop*, earlier *hicket*, *hyckock*, "a word meant to imitate the sound produced by the convulsion of the diaphragm" [Abram Smythe Farmer, "Folk-Etymology," London, 1882]. Cf. Fr. *hoquet*, Dan. *hikke*, etc. Modern spelling first recorded 1788

And:

> **hiccough**
> 1620s, variant of *hiccup* (q.v.) by mistaken association with *cough*.

So before standardisation of English spelling ([orthography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_orthography)), the onomatopoeic hiccup had many variations. We can see some of these in the [1831](http://books.google.fi/books?id=DZ4RAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA51&dq=hickop&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gaUlT_mmNaiP4gTX4aD_Ag&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=hickop&f=false) A critical review of the orthography of *Dr. Webster's Series of Books for Systematick Instruction in the English Language*.

And from the [Sesquiotica](http://sesquiotic.wordpress.com/2012/01/11/hiccough/) words, words, words blog:

> So anyway, this irritating thing produces a sound. Want to name it? Imitate the sound. For the most part, Western European languages don’t have a glottal stop as a separate phoneme, and certainly not a strong enough one to do the job here – uh-uh – so a /k/ will do, and /h/ for the sharp intake before it. Dutch has *hik*, as does Danish; Swedish has *hicka*; Breton has *hok*; French has *hoquet* and Latin has *hoquetus*; and English had, first, *hicket* and *hickock* (with various spellings, including *hitchcock*) and shortly thereafter *hiccup*, which from the 16th to 19th centuries showed a variety of alternative spellings: *hicke up, hikup, hickop, hickhop, hecup, hiccop, hickup, hick-up*…
>
> And somewhere in the 1600s, someone apparently got the idea that this word had come in part from *cough*. This was a time when words were being respelled by some people on the basis of their origins (real or false), which is how we got such weird messes as *debt*, *people*, and *island* (see “[What’s up with English spelling](http://sesquiotic.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/whats_up_with_english_spelling/)”). Sometimes the pronunciation changed, as with *falcon* (formerly *faucon*). But in the case of *hiccough*, the spelling was simply changed to reflect what was mistakenly thought to be its origin, but the pronunciation was kept the same.

As FumbleFingers suggested in a comment, it's a fair guess that after the *ck* had been lost to *hiccough* (due to a mistaken *hic* + *cough*) back in the early 1600s, the *cc* stuck around for the modern *hiccup* spelling of the late 1700s.

Answer (score -1):

A general rule of English pronunciation is that if a vowel is followed by two consonants, the vowel is long; if it's followed by a single consontant, the vowel is short. So "hicup" would be pronounced with a long "i". The double-c makes it a short "i".

Comment: But the typical way to indicate this is with a *ck,* not a *cc.* So the question, it seems to me, is not asking about a double consonant in general, but the double *c* in particular.

Comment: @BrettReynolds: Probably because the earlier spellings included *ck*, and then an alternate and intermediate re-spelling of *hiccough* on the mistaken belief it's from *cough*. See my [answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/56330/9001).